# Configure CameraX (flash mode, auto white balance mode, action mode etc)

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I've already successfully implemented CameraX, however, I am stuck on configuring its settings. I'd like to set auto white balance, noise reduction, flash and focus mode (just like in Camera2). So far, the only things I found on SO refer only to Camera2 and the official documentation doesn't tell me much either. Is it even possible to set these modes on CameraX or is only Camera2 supported so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct, the documentation is quite poor (I suppose because the library has been in alpha up until recently).

To change the flash mode:

Keep a reference to the `ImageCapture` object when binding:

```
    imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setFlashMode(ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)
        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
        .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
        .setTargetRotation(rotation)
        .build()
```

When you want to change the flash mode (e.g when the user taps the flash icon):

```
flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_OFF
```

Focus and metering are a little bit more involved, you can see the classes you should be using [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera2-core-1.0.0-alpha05).

As for noise reduction and white balance, I believe you'll need to still need to use the Camera2 libraries.

`implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"`

Comment: thanks! i've set the flash mode using the ImageCapture object and used a Camera2Interop.Extender to set my other requirements (i'm posting this comment just in case anyone else struggles with CameraX in the future ;-))

Comment: I'm also struggeling with the CameraX-Api to disable white balancing. Can you post code snippets (masterR0shi) ?

Comment: Can we add effects like black & white and greyscale in camerax preview?